# Emacs and intel debugger

Tags: emacs, ide, fortran

A coworke integrated the gdb into my emacs, so that i can single step through my code and it gets shown where i am in the emacs window. How do i do that with idb?

Unfortunately i cannot remember what we did then, so a walkthrough would be appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Software/Intel/Compilers/8.1/idb_release_notes.htm) or this [one](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=54711), you should be able to do:

```
M-x gdb
```

You'll be prompted `Run gdb (like this):` and you enter:

```
idb -gdb -fullname yourprogram.exe
```

As far as how to use the debugger, check out the current [gdb manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) and the [idb command reference](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/idb/idb_command_reference.pdf).

The gdb manual does have a [sample session](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session) (a walkthrough if you will).

Comment: that doesnt work. it starts the debugger, but when i go run, it wont actually execute something.

Comment: @tarrasch I don't have `idb`, so cannot test.  Did you specify the path to the executable?  When in the debugger, did you issue the `run arg1 arg2 ...` command to start it?

Comment: ah ok then. no it just freezes after starting idb. After issuing a command it wont do anything. i did everything according to those links, since i already found them before and tried.

Comment: @tarrasch The last piece of advice I can give is to verify that you can run `idb` from the command line (same arguments, but outside of Emacs).  If you can't, then there's your problem.  If you can... I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Trey Jackson actually from the command line everything works fine. i just want to have it in an IDE

Comment: i could have something. i used ddd to wrap the idb. that gives at least some support to a gui-debugger. I have managed to call ddd from emacs, but it still opens a new window. if there was some way to tell ddd to use the emacs window instead of opening its own i would be there.